# MySQL query using count on multiple tables

Tags: mysql

The query that I am trying to get is to "Show the agent with the most clients".

The tables that I am utilizing:

```
realtor(rid, fname, lname)     
contract(contractid, buyrid, buycid)      
property(pid, price, sellrid, sellcid)
```

What I am trying to do is make one table that has the buyrid and sellrid from contract and property and then count which rid is used the most. This is what I have that does not work:

```
SELECT r.rid, fname, lname
FROM realtor r, contract c, property p
WHERE r.rid = c.buyrid and r.rid = p.sellrid
GROUP BY c.buyrid, p.sellrid
HAVING count(*) >= ALL 
(SELECT count(*) 
FROM contract c, property p
GROUP BY c.buyrid, p.sellrid);
```

When I ran this in my database I got an empty set, which makes no sense. What am I doing wrong here? I have been working on this for a couple hours now and I am stuck, thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want to select the agent's id, first name and last name, with the most clients? realtor is the table with agents data. right?

Comment: Yeah I want to display the agent's information who has the most clients and the realtor table has the agents' data.

Comment: @cjw: Please do not add 'SOLVED' to your question. We already know you got an answer that helped you, that's what the [green check mark]((http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538)) in the left margin indicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  r.rid, 
        fname, 
        lname
FROM realtor AS r
INNER JOIN contract AS c ON r.rid=c.buyrid
INNER JOIN property AS p on r.rid=p.sellrid
GROUP BY r.rid
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you, inner join was exactly what I wanted but I didn't know the command.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this but here is what I'd be inclined to do:

```
SELECT r.rid,
       fname,
       lname,
       count(*) AS clients
  FROM realtor r
       LEFT JOIN contract c
          ON r.rid = c.buyrid
       LEFT JOIN property p
          ON r.rid = p.sellrid
 WHERE coalesce(c.buyrid, p.sellrid) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY r.rid
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

The `LEFT JOIN`s combined with `COALESCE` require an agent to have at least one client, and the order by and the limit enforce a return of just a single row.  I added the `count(*)` on the end to enable you to test the script a bit easier.